# How to provide/override the ResourceBaseName in default Localizer in .Net Core 2.2

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-localization

I would like to display localized Texts/Error Messages in .Net Core Mvc Identity Server4 application.  I tried to do the small PoC by following [.NetCore Globalization Guide my Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-2.2) and it works as expected.  I can display correct localized texts per requirements.

However, we've got an issue, when we applied it in the actual implementation.  We've got in-house built in framework for WebApplication and our .NetCore application is inheriting/implementing the base class & interfaces.  So, the built in .Net Core localizer are always trying to get the view translations by using the parent Namespace.

For example.
Current behaviour (Wrong)

```
application name = ttcg.MyCustomFramework.CustomNameSpace
ResourceBaseName = ttcg.MyCustomFramework.CustomNameSpace.Resources.Views.Account.Login
```

Expected bahaviour

```
application name = ttcg.IdentityServer
ResourceBaseName = ttcg.IdentityServer.Resources.Views.Account.Login
```

Please see the screenshot below:

[image]

I wrote `AddViewLocaliztion` per following in the StartUp class.  But, I don't know how to set the ResourceBaseName in the setup.

```
services.AddMvcCore().AddViewLocalization(
    LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.Suffix,
    options =>
    {
        options.ResourcesPath = "Resources";
    }
);
```

I tried to give the ResourceFile name with full namespace in the path (Eg. "ttcg.MyCustomFramework.CustomNameSpace.Resources.Views.Account.Login.en-GB.resx"), but it throws the path too long (over 260 characters) error.

Since I don't know how to overwrite it, I created the custom localizer service to inject in the views and it works.  However, the disadvantage is that, I've got a single Huge SharedResource file with multiple texts.

```cs
public class CustomLocalizerService
{
    private readonly IStringLocalizer _localizer;

    public CustomLocalizerService(IStringLocalizerFactory factory)
    {
        var type = typeof(SharedResource);
        var assemblyName = new AssemblyName(type.GetTypeInfo().Assembly.FullName);
        _localizer = factory.Create("SharedResource", assemblyName.Name);
    }

    public LocalizedString GetLocalizedHtmlString(string key)
    {
        return _localizer[key];
    }

    public LocalizedString GetLocalizedHtmlString(string key, string parameter)
    {
        return _localizer[key, parameter];
    }
}
```

So, it would be great if there is a way to make default .Net Core Localization provider work.  Is there anyway to provide or force .Net Core default localizer to use the provided namespace in ResourceBaseName?

Comment: Can you show a controller or a view where the localizer is injected?

Comment: I haven't done the injection in Controller yet.  Currently, I'm doing the injection in the view only.  But, if I do it in the Controller, it will be something like this (in my sample PoC app) https://github.com/ttcg/OAuthTest/blob/1d2fc6aecd6baadb3b230244dcf962d9621c3d0f/OAuthTest/OAuthTest.IDP/Quickstart/Account/AccountController.cs#L41

Comment: Like in your `CustomLocalizerService`, you can inject `IStringLocalizerFactory` in View/Controller and create a `IStringLocalizer` with a specific base name.

Comment: You meant, like following?  `@inject IStringLocalizer<SharedResources> SharedLocalizer`.  But this approach has two problems.  the resource file becomes huge and if I want to split to smaller files, I have to create multiple empty class files.  If this is the only way to achieve it, I might as well go with this approach.

Comment: In my case, I create multiple empty class.

Comment: Thanks Orwel, I ended up using multiple empty classes and put common texts in shared resource file.

Answer (score 0):

You can provide the namespace with `IStringLocalizerFactory`:

```cs
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    pricate readonly IStringLocalizer _localizer;

    public HomeController(IStringLocalizerFactory factory)
    {
        _localizer = factory.Create("Views.Account.Login","ttcg.IdentityServer");
    }
}
```

If you still